# Flutter MacOS Desktop Size

Tags: flutter-desktop

Hi I'm working on flutter macOS Desktop, How can I set Minimum windows size with they open the desktop app, I installed the desktop_window 0.4.0 from pub but how can I implement if they open the app it will automatically resize the desktop?